# How to get document/window height via js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get document/window height via js function in asp.net mvc view. How to do this? For example how to print into console or to alert message this value? How to locate js function into View?
Something like this?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

     console.log($(document).height());


 });
</script>
```

I newbie in js and asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you really need a jquery while you can use ...

```
window.innerWidth
```

and

```
window.innerHeight
```

which is the thing you want...

Comment: how to call and display this (window.innerWidth)? in View or where?for example how to display that value in ViewBag?

Comment: hey you can use it like , console.log(window.innerWidth);  or alert(window.innerWidth)); , to use it in server side , you can set some hidden field with this value like document.getElementByID('hdnClientWidth') = document.innerWidth; and than in asp.net mvc you can use by forms collection

Answer (score 0):

console.log($(document).height()) or console.log($(window).height()) -- It's same in most case.
If you explain more your task. It's wiil be more helpfull.

Comment: first, i want just to get these value(s) somewhere(console,alerts?) when i load a index page of site, and i don't know where to place this  function(in View Index.cshtml?)